# DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Tab Key Behavior

Tags: c#, datagridview, keypress, eventargs

I have DataGridView that organises student's points. When selected, I can enter points via DataGridViewTextBoxColumn. (the blue cells).

[image]

I use following code to control whether input is numeric or not.

```
    private void dgwPNotlar_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)    
    {
        e.Control.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(CheckKey);
    }

    private void CheckKey(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
            && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
            && e.KeyChar != 'G' && e.KeyChar !='M'&&e.KeyChar!='g'&&e.KeyChar!='m')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Which I want is when I finished entering points to current cell, the TAB key will take me to next student point cell. I tried to implement the code which controls pressed key above, but CheckKey method is not be fired when I press TAB key.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to insert "CellEndEdit" event from the DataGridView properties!

With this event you can press the "TAB", "ENTER" or each button you want.

I hope this will help you.